# Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I recently installed QGIS 3.18 in my Windows system. But when I installed "Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin", this error occured:

> Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin: Error. Check Python Matplotlib
> installation for the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin.

Can you give me some ideas about what may cause this?

Comment: What installer did you use for QGIS?  If you used the osgeo4W network install you could run it up again and make sure the matplotlib is installed, and if not add it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and I used the function in QGis: Plugins>>Manage and install plugin, then I installed but the error occured.

Comment: Besides, for the matplotlib, I used python console in Qgis and import matplotlib and there was no error like: no module named matplotlib so I think the matplotlib is in my Qgis but it could not be used by Qgis. Do you have any ideas about it? Thx!